# Obtener valores de input Subtotal, Impuesto, Total que se generan automáticamente al sumarse o multiplicar otros valores

Tags: javascript, reactjs, usestate

> Quiero obtener los valores de unos input que se rellenan solos,
> serian: Subtotal, Impuesto y Total, que son generados por los calculos
> de cierto precio de un producto y su cantidad (ej: 1500 * 2 = 3000 que
> seria el subtotal y este valor se agrega a otro input
> automaticamente); sin embargo con useState solo puedo obtener el valor
> si yo digito los valores en cada input pero no si son generados
> automáticamente, ya que, al agregar la cantidad, el valor no se
> agrega en Cantidad al instante sino hasta que entro a otro input y
> agrego otro valor.

```
   const initialState = {
    cliente: "",
    producto: "",
    precio: "",
    cantidad: "",
    subtotal: "",
    impuesto: "",
    total: ""
};

const [dataFactura, setDataFactura] = useState(initialState);

const subtotal = dataFactura.precio * dataFactura.cantidad;
const impuesto = subtotal * 0.15;
const total = subtotal + impuesto;

const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    
    setDataFactura( {
        ...dataFactura, 
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
    console.log(dataFactura)
    
}

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    
    console.log(dataFactura)

}


       <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
                <div className="row mb-4">
                    <div className="d-flex col-6">
                        <label className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Cliente:</label>
                        <div className="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="cliente" value={dataFactura.cliente} onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="d-flex col-6">
                        <label className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Fecha:</label>
                        <div className="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" readOnly className="form-control" value={fecha} onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="row mb-4">
                    <div className="col-4">
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="producto" value={dataFactura.producto} onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-3">
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="precio" value={dataFactura.precio} onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-3">
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="cantidad" value={dataFactura.cantidad} onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                    </div>
                    <button 
                        className="col-2 btn btn-primary"
                    >
                        Agregar
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row mt-2">
            <div className="col-7">
            {/* <div className="card">
                <div className="card-body">
                    <table className="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Producto</th>
                            <th scope="col">Precio</th>
                            <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                            <th scope="col">Total</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">1</th>
                                <td>Producto</td>
                                <td>Cantidad</td>
                                <td>Total</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div> */}
            </div>

           <div className="card col-5">
               <div className="row mt-2">
                    <div className="d-flex">
                        <label className="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Sub total:</label>
                        <div className="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" value={subtotal} onChange={handleInputChange} name="subtotal"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
               <div className="row mt-2">
                    <div className="d-flex">
                        <label className="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Impuesto:</label>
                        <div className="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" value={impuesto} onChange={handleInputChange} name="impuesto"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
               <div className="row my-2">
                    <div className="d-flex">
                        <label className="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Total:</label>
                        <div className="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" value={total} onChange={handleInputChange} name="total"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
               <div className="row mt-4 mb-2">
                    <div className="d-flex">
                        <label className="col-sm-6 col-form-label"></label>
                        <div className="col-sm-6 d-grid gap-2 mx-auto">
                            <button className="btn btn-success">Pagar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div> 
                        
        </div>
    </form>
```

> [image: Cita en bloque]

Answer (score 0):

Así lo solucione, agregando el siguiente codigo a la función de **handleInputChange()**. Espero le sirva a alguien!

```
   const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    // console.log(e.target.value);
    // console.log(e.target.name);
    const SubTotal = () => {
        if(e.target.name === "cantidad"){
            // console.log('es precio')
            const subT = (e.target.value * dataFactura.precio);
            return subT; 
        } 
    }

    const subTotal = SubTotal();
    const impuesto = subTotal * 0.15;
    const total = subTotal + impuesto;

    setDataFactura( {
        ...dataFactura, 
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        subtotal: subTotal,
        impuesto: impuesto,
        total: total,
    });
    console.log(dataFactura)
    
}
```